# Less permissions for a Foursquare app

Tags: permissions, foursquare

We would like to develop a survey in which consenting participants would have to give us access to their list of checkins on Foursquare. Currently, we do so via a Foursquare app, but I do not seem to find a way to specify which permissions our application needs.

Whenever a user is asked to grant access to our app, he is informed that we will be able to post checkins on his behalf and do a bunch of other things. This will raise concerns and will likely lower the number of willing participants.

The question would be whether there is a way to restrict the permissions of our app to what we actually need, i.e. the full list of checkins.
As an alternative, we are considering befriending the user from a special account instead. However, does friendship guarantee that we can see all of his checkins?

Answer (score 0):

The Foursquare API currently doesn't support scoped permissions (e.g., seeing check-ins only). You will have to make it clear to your users that you won't post to their accounts.

The only way to see a person's entire history of check-ins is if you have an access token for them, so unfortunately the befriending method won't work.